# What the pink area on the website it is when I using chrome dev tool in a rendering mode?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[image]

I am using chrome dev tools to optimize the performance of a website, can anyone expline what the pink area (at the bottom of the screenshot) it is?

The pink block area always shows when I scroll down/up the website.

This is the status of my chrome rendering debug switches.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I've never seen that. If you can provide a URL where I can reproduce, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue after the latest Chrome Canary update to 85.0.4152.0
Unsure which specific sites will trigger this, but 1Password interface is completely pink.

[image]
[image]